# Animating when re-positioning a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

As you can see in the attached code, `linearLayoutLogo` contains a `ProgressBar` and `TextView` and `linearLayoutReading` contains an `ImageView` and `TextView`. When `linearLayoutReading` is made visible the the two layouts reposition themselves around the center point due to `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

How can I animate `linearLayoutLogo` so it shifts upwards to its new position prior to `linearLayoutReading` becoming visible? Please see the attached [**video for an example**](http://tinypic.com/r/iy25gk/9).

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewRLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_accessibility_black_24dp"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAppTitle2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textColor="#CCFFFFFF"
            android:text="AppName"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutReading"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:text="Reading from device"
            android:textColor="#BF000000" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarSplash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public ProgressBar progressBarSplash;
public LinearLayout linearLayoutReading;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    linearLayoutReading = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutReading);
    linearLayoutReading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            linearLayoutReading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBarSplash = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBarSplash);
            progressBarSplash.setEnabled(true);
            progressBarSplash.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested it out on Android Studio. Just include `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in the top most `LinearLayout` (the one with `centerInParent` element).

Comment: That's actually astonishing. One line achieves exactly what I was after! Thank you very much.

Comment: My exact same reaction when I first encountered it before. Cheers! :D